# expected LP_c_float instance instead of list

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet, opengl-compat

I need to put an array in the function

```
material_diffuse = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
pgl.glMaterialfv(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, pgl.GL_DIFFUSE, material_diffuse) 

or 

material_diffuse = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
pgl.glMaterialfv(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, 
pgl.GL_DIFFUSE,ctypes.c_float(material_diffuse))
```

In the first case i get: expected LP_c_float instance instead of list
In the second: TypeError: must be real number, not list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [[MS.Docs]: glMaterialfv function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/opengl/glmaterialfv) (that *pyglet* wraps via [[Python 3.Docs]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes)), you should use:

```py
pgl.glMaterialfv(pgl.GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, pgl.GL_DIFFUSE, (pgl.GLfloat * len(material_diffuse))(*material_diffuse))
```

Other reference: [[searchcode]: pyglet - /experimental/buffer/torus.py](https://searchcode.com/file/8323159/experimental/buffer/torus.py).